# Is there a Windows 7 viewer for SQLite databases?

Tags: sqlite

I've used the excellent DB Browser for SQLite to create a simple database, but I want to "publish" the database so other people can view it read-only (search, use filters but not edit or add records). I can't see any way to do this with DB Browser, or any other tools I can find as they all provide editing support.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic. Anyway, what prevents these people from opening the DB file with another tool?

Comment: I agree with CL. Instead of searching for such SW, you might consider delivering the db on a read-only media such as CD-ROM. An other solution would be to set up a simple web server with a db viewer such as https://www.adminer.org/ and set the db file read-only on the server side.

Comment: This is for internal use within a small team. I don't really need to *prevent* other people from fiddling with the DB file, I just want to give them a simple way to view it and use filters without the distraction of viewing via an editor and possibly changing something accidentally. The frustrating thing is that a cut-down version of the DB Browser would be perfect, or even a cmd line switch to restrict it to be a viewer...